# "if you didn’t use imaginary numbers, the planes would have crashed."

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

This is an excerpt from [the transcript of a podcast](https://freakonomics.com/podcast/whats-wrong-with-shortcuts/).

> DU SAUTOY: One of the most extraordinary is that when we were trying
> to land planes using radar, it turned out the computers just weren’t
> fast enough to do the calculations if we just used normal numbers. But
> when we then exploited the power of imaginary numbers — which seemed
> sort of illegal because, you know, where are these numbers? — actually
> it allowed us to do the calculations much more quickly. And so we
> understood where the planes were, we were able to land them, whilst **if
> you didn’t use imaginary numbers**, the planes would have crashed.

My sense is that the clause in bold should be changed to 'if you hadn't used imaginary numbers'.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

But if speaking in a formal register and/or for clarity's sake I would also change "you" to "one".

There is also something else that is incorrect in the sentence. If I understand what they are saying correctly,"so" ought to be changed to "as".

Other things indicate that the passage relates to a loose and conversational register - which doesn't always follow the rules of grammar.

Comment: I think it should remain "so" as I read it to mean the same as "because". As in "Because we have used imaginary numbers to work out where the planes are, we are able to land them"

Comment: @PeterJennings  I would accept "because" - but "so" is no substitute for "because", is it? At the moment it reads *So we understood where the planes were, we were able to land them.* I am not even 100% clear what it it is meant to mean.  The second part of the sentence is a non-sequitur of the first.